# In rails 4.0, not able to run "rails generate rspec <users>" command

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, generator

I am using rails 4.0.

I am trying to create one rspec file using below command

```
$ rails generate rspec static_pages
```

but this command is not working, it is showing below error

```
DEPRECATION WARNING: config.whiny_nils option is deprecated and no longer works. (called   from block in <top (required)> at   /home/shruthi/Projects/samples/tutorials/config/environments/development.rb:10)
config.eager_load is set to nil. Please update your config/environments/*.rb files accordingly:

* development - set it to false
* test - set it to false (unless you use a tool that preloads your test environment)
* production - set it to true

Could not find generator rspec.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get a list of installed generators by typing "rails generate"

To generate a spec file for the user model, try:

```
rails generate rspec:model user
```

As noted here https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/docs/generators and here https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails

Comment: how to create rspec for static pages?

Comment: I don't know that there is a generator for that, but you could start with a view spec and copy to a new file in the spec folder or a subfolder, and modify it so it tests your static page.

Comment: If I try to install bootstrap plugin using "$ rails generate bootstrap:install", i will get below error,

Could not find generator bootstrap:install

Comment: Do you have the 'twitter-bootstrap-rails' gem installed?  See https://github.com/seyhunak/twitter-bootstrap-rails and the Railscast on Bootstrap http://railscasts.com/episodes/328-twitter-bootstrap-basics

Comment: yea.. After installing 'twitter-bootstrap-rails' gem it is working fine. Thank You.